# Twitter REST API Retrieve user interest

Tags: php, rest, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm experimenting with twitter API, and have successfully authenticated the user. 
But i also need a way to get the user interest.
Also followed this [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/analytics/overview). Here I could not find a way to get user interest Or do I need a third party application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no API from Twitter that provides the interests of an individual user account, even in the Ads API. The Ads API (which you need to apply for whitelisted access to) will enable interest-based targeting for promoted Tweets, but it will not provide user-level interest data.